# why is GAE returning server error when the code works in the local development server?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to test the Datastore functionality using Google App Engine and my code works as expected in the local development server:

```
// code based on the following guide: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-go
package datastoretest

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "cloud.google.com/go/datastore"
        "google.golang.org/appengine" 
)

type Task struct {
        Description string
}

func init() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    ctx := appengine.NewContext(r)

    // Set Google Cloud Platform project ID.
    projectID := "myProjectID" //note: actual ID is different

    // Creates a client.
    client, err := datastore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create client: %v", err)
    }

    // Sets the kind for the new entity.
    kind := "Task"
    // Sets the name/ID for the new entity.
    name := "sampletask1"
    // Creates a Key instance.
    taskKey := datastore.NameKey(kind, name, nil)

    // Creates a Task instance.
    task := Task{
            Description: "Buy milk",
    }

    // Saves the new entity.
    if _, err := client.Put(ctx, taskKey, &task); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to save task: %v", err)
    }

    fmt.Fprint(w, "Saved ", taskKey, ":", task.Description)

}
```

However, after being deployed to a GAE project, it's returning the following message to the visitor:

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Comment: The error is telling you that the application exited. The application probably exited because of a call to log.Fatalf. Use the [appengine loggger](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/logs/reference) to log the error and return from the handler instead of calling log.Fatalf.  Look at the error in the console to determine what might be wrong.

Comment: I used the appengine logger and removed the regular log package, but removing log.Fatalf did not stop the problem. It appears that the function client.Put is a cause of the problem, as commenting it out makes the webpage load ok, but why?

Comment: What's the error returned from Put?

Comment: I couldn't see error from Put specifically. The page just kept loading and eventually the log said "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application." Then it said "Process terminated because the request deadline was exceeded. (Error code 123)"

Comment: I have another problem with this code that may be related: upon checking with the local datastore at http://localhost:8000/datastore, it appears that the entity was not actually being saved: "Datastore has no entities in the Empty namespace." Yet, client.Put did not produce an error since returned error = nil.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the use of the package "cloud.google.com/go/datastore" was causing the problem. Instead, the solution should have been implemented using the package "google.golang.org/appengine/datastore". It appears that the former package was not compatible with GAE in my implementation. Switching to the latter package led to working code. For Datastore in GAE a better tutorial to follow should have been the following: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/getting-started/creating-guestbook

Comment: A better tutorial than what? If there's a tutorial out there that calls for using the wrong library, it needs to be fixed.

Comment: The code was taken from this one: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-go

Comment: (That page didn't use the appengine package, so maybe it's my own fault for trying to adapt it this way, but the two versions are confusingly similar for me and some users even suggested we could use either one)